# While loop creating infinite loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, infinite-loop

So I'm creating a program for a C++ class, and I created a while loop to stop invalid inputs.
Every time I do test it with an invalid input it goes into an infinite loop. I'm new to coding, so I really don't know how to fix it.

```
 cout << "Enter weight in ounces (Max: 1800)" << endl;
    cin >> pkgweight;

    while (pkgweight > 0 || pkgweight < 1800)
    {
        cout << "Weight out of range. Program terminating.\n" << endl;
    }

    cout << "Enter miles shipping (Max: 3500)" << endl;
    cin >> distance;

    while (distance > 0 || distance < 3500)
    {
        cout << "Shipping distance out of range." << endl;
        cout << "Program terminating.\n" << endl;
    }
```

Comment: Take a closer look at the condition `while(pkgweight > 0 || pkgweight < 1800)` and ask if there's any possible value of `pkgweight` that would make that `false`. Then, after you fix it, ask yourself how it ever could _change_ from `true` to `false` if you never assign a new value to `pkgweight` during the body of the `while` loop.

Comment: Why are these `while` loops rather than `if` conditions?  "Program terminating" should be followed by something like `std::terminate()`.

Comment: Thank you guys! Was going to look for a terminate code myself as well, and thanks for trying to explain it to me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If nothing changes inside that loop, the exit condition will never be tripped.

Maybe you mean:

```
int pkgweight = 0;

cout << "Enter weight in ounces (Max: 1800)" << endl;
cin >> pkgweight;

if (pkgweight < 0 || pkgweight > 1800)
{
  cout << "Weight out of range. Program terminating.\n" << endl;
}
```

You'll want to use `while` for situations where you want to loop until some condition is met. `if` is like a non-looping `while`.

> While it's great that you're learning and it's understood you're going to make mistakes, slipping up on something this fundamental is usually a sign you don't have a good reference to work from. Get yourself a solid [C++ reference book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) and refer to it often if you're ever stumped about something. This is *essential* for learning properly, not just picking up bits and pieces here and there and trying to intuit the gaps. Many parts of C++ will not make sense, they are artifacts of design decisions decades old and the influence of other programming languages you've never heard of. You need a proper foundation.

Comment: Thanks for the input! From the screenshots my professor provided it didn't seem he wanted an additional input after the error message so I didn't add it. I didn't realize that because of the nature of while loops it makes the infinite loop without the input correction. I'll definitely look into the reference book as well :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want the user to be able to fix an incorrectly entered input, you would want:

```
 cout << "Enter weight in ounces (Max: 1800)" << endl;
 cin >> pkgweight;

 while (pkgweight > 0 || pkgweight < 1800)
 {
     cout << "Weight out of range. Program terminating.\n" << endl;
     cout << "Enter weight in ounces (Max: 1800)" << endl;
     cin >> pkgweight;
 }
```

That way, if the user enters a number which is outside of the valid range, they will be prompted to enter a new number. If the new value is within the range, the loop will exit.

The problem with your current program is that a `while` loop will execute "while" the condition it checks for is `true`. In your current program, once `pkgweight` is set, it stays the same value. This means that if the loop is entered because the condition it checks for is `true`, that condition will never change (allowing the loop to exit), and your error message will be printed indefinitely.

Comment: My professor didn't want the input correction so that's why I was having the problem. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code, it seems like you want to kill the program if the input is wrong. You could consider terminating the function. Is this all in `main()`? If it is not in an external function, just do `return -1`. I know this is probably bad programming practice, but hey, it works specifically for this!
By the way, your conditional said `> 0` and `< 1800`, which means the program will terminate *if* the variables distance and pkgweight are in the specified range.
Here is my working snippet without these errors, tested on [onlineGDB](https://www.onlinegdb.com).

```
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
 int main ()
 {
    int pkgweight, distance;
    cout << "Enter weight in ounces (Max: 1800)" << endl;
    cin >> pkgweight;

    while (pkgweight < 0 || pkgweight > 1800)
    {
        cout << "Weight out of range. Program terminating.\n" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    cout << "Enter miles shipping (Max: 3500)" << endl;
    cin >> distance;

    while (distance < 0 || distance > 3500)
    {
        cout << "Shipping distance out of range." << endl;
        cout << "Program terminating.\n" << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Of course, instead of switching the less-than and greater-than, you could always wrap the conditional in a not operator.

Comment: Wrapping the conditional in a not operator would be incorrect. `pkgweight > 0 || pkgweight < 1800` is equivalent to `true`. `while(false)` is not actually better than `while(true)` here.